# Word to describe decoding LED color / blinking in electronics?

Tags: single-word-requests

Light Emitting Diodes (LEDs) are used in electronics to indicate status of an electronic device. I believe I have seen a single word specific for this purpose.

For example a network switch will have an LED for each port: typically a lit green LED is used to indicate a device is connected and an unlit LED is an unconnected port. When data is flowing, the LED will blink.   A red LED is often used to communicate a failure or dangerous condition in electronics.

Some devices have LEDs that can emit different colors and all LEDs can be switched on or blinking.

What is the word used to describe the rules to decode the meaning of LED colors / blinking?

Example.  Dear tech support:  Please forward the LED ????? to interpret the status details of the network switch.

Comment: What sentence are you thinking of for the word?

Comment: Your own term “decode” seems to describe what you’re after.

Comment: "Blink codes"? It's not even clear what part of speech you're looking for

Comment: Assuming you are focusing on "rules" for these *status* indicators... there aren't any.  You can make a device that blinks red when it's functioning properly.   So, you want a name for the secret decoder ring?  *The manual*.

Comment: Maybe *legend*.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample sentence. I'd consider *protocol*.

Comment: Perhaps "rubric" would work. In a less formal register, "cheat sheet"

Comment: This is a technical question not a general usage one, and assuming you're wanting the specific term used in electronics/hardware contexts, you might get a more authoritative answer somewhere like https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/ or one of the other specialist boards.